# What does single colon mean c++ function interface

Tags: c++

I saw this function in c++ code

```
GRenderWindow::GRenderWindow(QWidget* parent, EmuThread* emu_thread)
    : QWidget(parent), child(nullptr), emu_thread(emu_thread) {

    std::string window_title = Common::StringFromFormat("yuzu %s| %s-%s", Common::g_build_name,
                                                        Common::g_scm_branch, Common::g_scm_desc);
    setWindowTitle(QString::fromStdString(window_title));

    InputCommon::Init();
}
```

What does the single colon mean?
Does the part after the single colon means return?

```
 .... : QWidget(parent), child(nullptr), emu_thread(emu_thread) {}
```

Original code: https://github.com/yuzu-emu/yuzu/blob/master/src/yuzu/bootmanager.cpp

Comment: parent constructor call and instance variable initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the start of a [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).